# Lucene Query Syntax Search

Tags: database, search, lucene

Total novice when it comes to Lucene Query Syntax so need a bit of help!

Searching a database by email and using

```
email: <someone's email here>
```

in the URL as the search param.

How would one go about implementing this so it would only return the record with the exact email address?

So if I were to search

```
email: test@gmail.com
```

and the database contained a 'test@email.com' and 'test@gmail.com' only the latter would be returned?

I've had a look at http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html however the answer eludues me.

Any help would be much appreciated as always!

Answer (score 1):

This is analyzer's question.

If you want search the exact word, you should build the address field with `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`, then the address "test@email.com" will be analyze to "test@email.com".

The code like this：

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("email", "test@email.com", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```